# SQL Query with Powershell - Return Values not maching

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

So I have some code I wrote to take the input form a text file and run some sql checks against another database I populated:

```
$volOutput = gc C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\mutant.txt 

foreach ($m in $volOutput) { 

  $check = $m.split()[-1] | select -Unique

  foreach ($c in $check) {
    #$c - this lists all of them so the foreach is working...

    # Build the connection and search the db for $c names.
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $conn.ConnectionString = "Server=(localdb)\mutex; Database=MutexObjects"
    $conn.Open()
    $db = $conn.CreateCommand()
    $db.CommandText = "select Names from Objects WHERE Names='$c'"
    $db.ExecuteScalar()
    $conn.Close()    

  } # Foreach Check

} # First foreach
```

The return values I get are:

```
PS C:\> B:\Programming\powershell\parse_vol.ps1
ZonesCounterMutex
ZoneAttributeCacheCounterMutex
ZonesCacheCounterMutex
ZoneAttributeCacheCounterMutex
ZonesLockedCacheCounterMutex
ZonesCounterMutex
ZoneAttributeCacheCounterMutex
ZonesCacheCounterMutex
ZoneAttributeCacheCounterMutex
ZonesLockedCacheCounterMutex
```

Which is correct, but it's also missing a lot more. If I take individual samples and run queries from within SQL management studio for example, I get:

I populated the word "test" in each list as a....test.

```
Select Names From Objects WHERE Names='test'

Names

test
```

But I don't see test on the output from the above code. There are about 5 or 6 more than it's missing that I have validated manually by querying the db w/in SQL management studio.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the file content against the full list of Names from the database:

```
$filecontent = Get-Content "C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\mutant.txt" `
          | % { $_.split()[-1] } `
          | select -Unique

$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Server=(localdb)\mutex; Database=MutexObjects"
$conn.Open()
$dbwrite = $conn.CreateCommand()
$dbwrite.CommandText = "SELECT Names FROM Objects"

$reader = $dbwrite.ExecuteReader([System.Data.CommandBehavior]::CloseConnection)
$dbcontent = while ( $reader.Read() ) { $reader[0] }

$conn.Close()    

Compare-Object $filecontent $dbcontent
```

Does `Compare-Object` show differences?

Comment: Yes, a lot for both <= and = (more to the $filecontent <=)

Comment: The names with a `<=` side indicator are not present in the database, so it's unsurprising that they're not listed by your script.

Comment: So I actually went back and looked. I was missing some, and I think this was working all along... In either case, I like your response and gave you credit.